# Assign value to struct array without function

Tags: c, struct, clang, assign

I am currently working on a device manager but encountered a problem...
As shown i declared a struct array which is supposed to hold the writer function of a device (vga, serial)... The main issue is that i don't want to call an initialize function, e.g vga_init() or serial_init() to assign them to the structure, tbh that would lose sense... Rather i wanna have those functions stored in an struct array, is there a way to assign vga_write/serial_write without a function, like shown below (Notice the two comments)?

Thanks for incoming advices!

```
/* device.h */

#define vga    0
#define serial 1

/* device info structure */

struct device_io {
    void (*write)(const char *str);
}

extern struct device_io *io[];


/* vga.c */

io[vga] = { .wr = &vga_write };           // Won't work!
void vga_write(const char *str) { ...

/* serial.c */

io[serial] = { .wr = &serial_write };     // Won't work also!
void serial_write(const char *str) { ...
```

Comment: @M.Aroosi Nope, that's not true. `vga` has to be a separate word to be replaced, so `vga_write` won't be affected.

Comment: The macro substitution will produce `info[0] = { .wr = &vga_write }; // Won't work!` but there is no `info[]` array in sight. And, function `vga_write` is unknown at that point - it is defined next.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to write info[] :P Info has been struct device_io *io[]; vga_write and serial_write are declared on top. The question is, how can i assign those function to the io-struct without calling a function which assigns them

Comment: like, e.g io[vga] = { .wr = &vga_write }; It throws me an error when it isn't inside a function... Short said, i want to initialize the array without a function..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outside of a function you can only use an initializer expression to assign a value to a global (or static or bss) variable.

That in turn means the initializer expression you're using must initialize the entire array at once, like so:

```
static int test[] = { 4, 5, 6 };
```

, which, of course, can be extended to arbitrary data like function pointers or structs

```
void some_func0(const char *v) { }
void some_func1(const char *v) { }
static void (*test[])(const char *) = { &some_func0, &some_func1 };
```

. As you can see though, this requires that all the functions you intend to use are at least *declared* before the initializer. At the point of declaration of the array in your question (in "device.h") I presume you don't know all implementations.

However, you need to have a source file somewhere in your program where you do know all array elements at once. To work around this, you can restructure your code like:

---

device.h

```
extern void (*test[])(const char *); // <-- or your struct type
```

vga.h

```
extern void vga_write(const char *);
```

vga.c

```
void vga_write(const char *c) {...
```

device_array_initialization_helper_this_is_a_very_verbose_file_name.c

```
#include "device.h"
#include "vga.h"

// Definition of the array, which is declared in device.h
void (*test[])(const char *) = { &vga_write, ... };
```

---

Of course, you can use your struct type as well.

Comment: Thanks alot! Thats exactly what i needed to know, awesome help! :)